# Google Analytics - What is the difference between old and new version?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am confused about two different kinds of GA snippets. A customer send us both snippets to track different language uses. The first one is for the main domain (www.example.com) the second one for another language (www.example.com/en). Note that the url in the second one is just the main domain (www.example.com) without the language.

Number one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'here-be-a-code']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Number Two:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'here-be-a-code', 'here-be-url');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

As I understand it number 1 is the 'old' version while number 2 is the 'new' one.

Is there a difference between those two? Or could I just use the second one for both cases (with adjusted Account-codes of course)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use both codes interchangeably. Each code belongs to a specific version of Google Analytics and the account (update: it's property, not account) needs to be configured accordingly.

You could, in theory, use the "old" code for both sites since Google says that the old code will work for Universal Analytics enabled properties  until UA is out of beta. However there is no good reason to do so. Plus the asychronous code will not support some features of UA such as custom metrics and dimensions.

You cannot at all use the new code for properties that are configured for asynchronous analytics.

However your client should upgrade his old property to universal analytics since [Google has announced](http://analytics.blogspot.de/2013/10/an-easy-way-to-upgrade-to-universal_23.html) that they will "auto-transfer" old properties to UA if you do not upgrade manually (there is now a way to keep historical data) and I guess it's better to stay in control of the process.

Edit to add:

Vou can have multiple properties in one account and the difference between asynchronous and universal analytics is configured on a property level, not per account (so you can have different versions in one account).

The tracker ids in the code above should differ in the last digit (if they are the same than this is indeed wrong).

Comment: That seems to make sense, but both snippets come from the same Account. Does that make sense to you?But I think I will use the old version for now (because it's time sensitive) and then tell the client to get his act together ;)

Comment: Yes, they differ only in the last digit. Thanks for the insight!